# Separability of graph component embeddings

Tags: graph-theory, curves-and-surfaces, embeddings, polygons

I have an undirected graph. I also have an embedding of the graph in $\mathbb{R}^3$. Assume that the graph has 2 connected components. I want to know whether there exists a plane (or better - any surface topologically equivalent to a plane) which separates the embedded components such that each of the two components' embeddings are placed in different half-spaces.

The embedding is a grid-like structure, we could assume that each edge is embedded as a line of unit length, but the positioning of the vertices is kind of irregular.

This means the embedding is actually composed of some polygons in $\mathbb{R}^3$ and it should perhaps be enough to assume that each of the components is simply a cycle and then check for each pair of cycles. A cycle is embedded by a single (generally nonconvex) polygon, so the core of the problem could thus perhaps be rephrased in terms of some polygons in $\mathbb{R}^3$. Informally, some of the cases I wish to distinguish are the following:

1. The polygons are positioned side-by-side. Easily separable by a plane if convex. Separable by the more general surface if non-convex.
2. One of the polygons is "inside" the other. Not separable by a plane, but separable by the surface.
3. The polygons are interlocked in a chain-like structure. Not separable at all.

How could I approach solving this?

Comment: This is at least as hard as the unknotting problem